# Wifi using Overlapping - Channel 3 and Channel 5

Tags: wifi

I see a wireless network (802.11b) set to channel 3 and another on channel 5 - both with similar, but not the same SSID (SLR_UNIQUE-PORTION-HERE), near my house. From the MAC, I see they are using Ubiquiti (http://www.ubnt.com/) equipment - read as commercial deployment.

Assuming they know what they were doing, what reasons would they have to use overlapping channels, and not put their network on channels 1, 6 or 11?

As well, I see both are using different SSID's and being on different channels, are they using these in tandem or with the same client side equipment, in other words, why didn't they use the same channel and SSID?

What issues will I have being on channel 1, or 6 with them being on 3 & 5? Will my reception be any worse than if they were also on 1 or 6?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming they know what they were doing, what reasons would they have to use overlapping channels, and not put their network on channels 1, 6 or 11?

If they did a proper deployment they did a site survey and those channels gave them the best reception in the areas they put them in. But really without asking them ... it's all just conjecture and guesswork.

> As well, I see both are using different SSID's and being on different channels, are they using these in tandem or with the same client side equipment, in other words, why didn't they use the same channel and SSID?

There could be any number of reasons for this ... my best guess - network segmentation.  But really without asking them ... it's all just conjecture and guesswork.

> What issues will I have being on channel 1, or 6 with them being on 3 & 5? Will my reception be any worse than if they were also on 1 or 6?

Unless they are right next door to you ... you shouldn't have any issues. Their signal will in all probability not be strong enough to interfere with yours at that point in such a way as to make a noticeable impact on your reception.